# Streamlit aggrid with autocomplete cells

Tags: ag-grid, streamlit

So I don't have any code snippet since I can't figure out how to even start it.

I'm trying to create a simple streamlit that will have a button that loads a CSV file and displays it in and editable aggrid. so far so good.

Then, when a button is clicked I would like it to add an empty row to the aggrid.

Now, here is the hard part that I can't figure out.

Say I loaded a CSV file that has 2 columns of ID and name that looks like this:

1 test1
2 test2
3 test3
4 notes

when I stand in an empty cell of name and start typing "te", I would like it to suggest the options test1, test2, test3, and so on.

I tried a simple example using streamlit_tags but it always suggested me only 1 option like test1 and I also didn't manage to do it inside aggird.

Does anyone have an idea?

thank you